# VBA font color loop

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a VBA code that loops through different colors. For example. when I press ctrl + m the first time I want it to be blue, then if I press the same shortcut it becomes red and then etc with other colors. Also would like to be able to add and take out colors if I need to change them so if someone can explain the color array part of their equation that would be great for me to make edits myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This website provides a chart of the basic 56 colors](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm#chart).  A search on 'Color Palette' will help you find others if needed.  Arrays begin at 0, so I advise keeping the array this way.  Using the chart I linked, you can add as many colors to the array as you want.  Just make sure to update the number sequence for ColorArray and change the ReDim line to the last number in the sequence.

Assign the code below to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> and **delete either the background or font color portion of code**.  Whatever cell(s) you have selected when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> will change to the next array color.  Make sure the selection is all the same color, though.  This isn't written with multiple color selections in mind.

```
Sub SetColor()
    Dim ColorArray() As Long
    Dim ColorBg As Long
    Dim ColorFont As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim changed As Boolean

    ReDim ColorArray(2)
    ColorArray(0) = 3       'Red
    ColorArray(1) = 4       'Green
    ColorArray(2) = 5       'Blue

'Use this if you want to change cell background color

    'Find background color to check against
    ColorBg = Selection.Interior.ColorIndex
    'Loop through array to find a match
    For counter = LBound(ColorArray) To UBound(ColorArray)
        If ColorBg = ColorArray(counter) Then
            'Match found, assign next color in array
            If UBound(ColorArray) < counter + 1 Then
                Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorArray(0)
            Else
                Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorArray(counter + 1)
            End If
            'Exit loop early, changed=True so 1st color isn't reassigned
            changed = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next counter
    'No match found in array, assign 1st array color
    If changed = False Then Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorArray(0)

'Use this if you want to change font color

    'Find background color to check against
    ColorBg = Selection.Font.ColorIndex
    'Loop through array to find a match
    For counter = LBound(ColorArray) To UBound(ColorArray)
        If ColorBg = ColorArray(counter) Then
            'Match found, assign next color in array
            If UBound(ColorArray) < counter + 1 Then
                Selection.Font.ColorIndex = ColorArray(0)
            Else
                Selection.Font.ColorIndex = ColorArray(counter + 1)
            End If
            'Exit loop early, changed=True so 1st color isn't reassigned
            changed = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next counter
    'No match found in array, assign 1st array color
    If changed = False Then Selection.Font.ColorIndex = ColorArray(0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to this macro:

```
Sub CNTRLm()
    With ActiveCell.Font
        If .ColorIndex = 56 Then
           .ColorIndex = 1
        Else
        .ColorIndex = .ColorIndex + 1
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```